# Configure kvm (libvirt) routed network on Ubuntu 16.04 host

Tags: networking, ubuntu-16.04, kvm, virsh

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 KVM hypervisor behind a Debian-based firewall, and I'm trying to make the guest VMs IP-reachable, preferably matching the subnet I'm using for that collection of machines.

The firewall is hosting a 10.4.0.0/16 network, and successfully NAT'ing and accepting applicable traffic.

The **hypervisor** is at 10.4.20.250, with the virsh network configuration shown below. Of note, I've extended the netmask to try separating the clients from the host:

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>02b5de1a-cde4-45dd-b8f5-a9fdfa1c6809</uuid>
  <forward mode='route'/>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:a3:f0:e9'/>
  <ip address='10.4.20.20' netmask='255.255.255.128'>
  </ip>
</network>
```

The hypervisor (10.4.20.250) also has the following:

```
# ip r
default via 10.4.0.1 dev enp0s25 onlink 
10.4.0.0/16 dev enp0s25  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.4.20.250 
10.4.20.0/25 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.4.20.20 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s25  scope link  metric 1000 

# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
virbr0      8000.fe54009e64d0   yes     vnet0

# ip link show virbr0
3: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:9e:64:d0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

# virsh domiflist myguest
Interface  Type       Source     Model       MAC
-------------------------------------------------------
vnet0      bridge     virbr0     virtio      52:54:00:9e:64:d0
```

The **guest** ("myguest") at 10.4.20.25 is able to reach the internet at large; it's configured with:

```
ip r
default via 10.4.20.20 dev eth0 
10.4.0.0/17 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.4.20.25
```

From a terminal session connected to the hypervisor (10.4.20.250), I can ping itself, the bridge at 10.4.20.20, the guest at 10.4.20.25, the firewall at 10.4.0.1, and the internet at large.

From the firewall (10.4.0.1) I can ping the hypervisor (10.4.20.250) and the bridge (10.4.20.20) .. but pings to the client (10.4.20.25) are lost. Similarly, from another machine on the 10.4 network, I can ping the firewall, the hypervisor, and the bridge, but not the client. I have the following rules set:

```
ip r
default via 10.4.0.1 dev enp4s0 onlink 
10.4.0.0/16 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.4.2.1 
10.4.20.0/25 via 10.4.20.20 dev enp4s0 
192.168.15.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.15.242
```

Any help what configuration I might be missing to make my client be reachable from remote devices?

*Note*, I have tried to set the forward mode as 'open' but virsh net-edit gives me the following error:
*error: unsupported configuration: unknown forwarding type 'open'*